# Are there any good Raspberry Pi distributions that load completely into RAM?

Tags: operating-systems

Are there any good Raspberry Pi distributions that load completely into RAM?

I know a few Linux x86 distributions that do this pretty well, but I want to do the same with my Raspberry Pi.

I would like to be able to boot from the SD card and then be able to remove it without errors.

Comment: You might want to look at this first: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=48662&p=380872 There *might* be a module you could `rmmod` to stop that but OTOH: the source seems to be a hardware interrupt, indicating the pi responds to badly to the missing SD card.

Comment: I don't know if you know about the Linux distro "Puppy Linux", but the desktop edition runs completely on RAM. They've made a Raspi version called [Puppi](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Puppi), but I'm not sure if that version runs completely on RAM

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is; my project Nard SDK
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/ 
does exactly what you want. It's a slimmed OS which runs entirely from RAM and has full support for removing the SD card in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out this operating system called [slack linux.](http://www.slackware.com/)  I did not try this with the pi but with a computer with 1 GB of ram. Therefore I beleive it would work on the Pi 2 because of the amount of ram.  Here is a [site](http://rpi2.fatdog.eu/) for putting it on the Pi2.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/) loads into RAM. In its default configuration, it mounts a squashfs from the SD card for kernel modules and firmware, but you should be able to disable that; you may need to arrange for more modules to be in the initfs (via flags to the `update-kernel` program) depending on what other hardware and capabilities you are using.

I am currently running it in "data" mode (where `/var` is mounted from the SD card, but the base system is in RAM) on a Pi Zero W, and it is working well.